# Need positioning arms for soldering 0201

Tags: surface-mount

I'm looking for some kind of micro positioning arm to help me solder wires on tiny SMD devices.  Some kind of pantograph mechanism where my hands move much further than the tip controlling the wire.  It would also have to have to hold/release the wire.  Of course, this all has to work without blocking the view of the microscope.

I'm guessing this has been invented, if I only knew what to call it.

I find myself soldering boards with 0201 parts and 0.4mm pitch ICs.  Even with a stereo microscope, my hands just aren't up to the task.  I know of the traditional "helping hands", but they are hard to adjust precisely and the usual alligator clip end is too large (blocks my view).

Update:
I should mention that the board was machine placed and I'm just trying to do rework on it.  If it was up to me, bigger parts would have been used!

Comment: If you must solder a wire to an SMD part, you tin the wire, put a blob of solder on the end of the SMD part, and get a blob of solder on the iron.  Place the wire on the SMD pad, heat it and push the wire into the the solder with the iron.  Two handed job, no problem.  Attach the other end of the wire then glue it down.  then you can examine the joints and resolder if needed.

Comment: Asking for a gadget and where to get it is off topic.  Your question has gotten votes to close for that reason.

Comment: Setting aside if your particular task is realistic and how much better a paste stenciled board generally works, the closer to the work you can brace your hand or rest a finger, the better.  You'll note that modern fine tip soldering irons have a much shorter distance from the tip to the handle.

Answer (score 1):

Soldering discrete wires to 0201 components is a lost cause. If you really need to use discrete parts in a wired circuit purchase 0805 parts or axial leaded parts.

Soldering 0201 parts to a circuit board with properly designed footprints is a doable task but can be challenging. Probably the best scheme for hand type assembly is to use solder paste on the pads, then place the component and solder with a directed flow hot air source or use a reflow process.

Answer (score 1):

0201 imperial parts are rather tiny & 0201 metric are insanely small for hand assembly. Consider using 0603 (imperial)parts which look like bricks under a microscope with modest magnification

Anyway, assuming you have a real need, do a web search for "micromanipulator". There are some good youtube videos on SMD rework techniques too (eg. SolderingGeek who covers  IPC J-STD-001), but I don't know if they cover your specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The pantoprobe is mostly what I want:
https://hackaday.com/2017/10/04/precision-pantograph-probes-pcbs/

I would not of found it without Spehro mentioning to look for micromanipulators on YouTube.  So he get the assist.

Comment: Interesting. The flexure approach should have negligible backlash/slop. An imperial 0201 is 300um x 600um so you'd want fairly tight or preloaded joints. Miniature ball bearings might be an option.